# Establecer conexión entre NPM WhatApp Web.js y Express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, backend, whatsapp

Quisiera saber de como modo puedo establecer una conexión en el código, debido a que el NPM de WhatsApp Web.js es parecido al de Express donde ambos usan un puerto como servidor

```
//Establezco una sesion de WA con el NPM Wa Web.js
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Confirmo que se conecto con el numero WA
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Chatbot conectado....');
});
//Se Maneja el mensaje que enviaran los usuarios a través de WA
client.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg.body);
});
//El comando que ejecuta la conexion de WA Web
client.initialize();

//Comandos propios de Express
app.post('/conversacion/', async function (req, res) {

//establezco los parametros de watson
const { text, context = {} } = await req.body;

//Le paso los parametros
    const params = {
        input: { text },
        workspaceId:'<>',
        context: context,
    };

//Recibo la respuesta de Watson
    await assistant.message(params, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(response);
        }
    });

});
app.listen(port);
```

Mi objetivo es que el puerto de Express reciba el mensaje de WhatsApp Web.js y los procese con Watson Assistant, no tuve problemas en conectar Watson con Express, pero si tengo dificultades en conectar WhatsApp web.js con Express